# Function app to load data from .csv in azure data lake store to azure sql server

Tags: azure-function-app

I have a .csv file in azure data lake store, Is there a way to load the data from that file to azure sql server using Function app? Currently I am using ADF to load the data.

Thanks,
Rav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [Azure Data Lake Store Binding for Azure Functions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-datalake-extension). It supports input and output bindings.

[Samples](https://joeraio.com/azure-data-lake-extension-for-azure-functions/)